# would change process priority frequently have side effect

Tags: unix, process

I am doing embedded system programming.
our process is set as higher priority by default, however for some actions like invoking shell command, write file. I was thinking to lower its priority and then up it again. so it's kind of like a pair of function calling: "setdefaultpriority" and "improve priority".

And there are lots of shell command calling in our process. In one file, I may need to call tens of pair of "setdefault..." and "improve.."

My question, would so many priority operation in one process have any bad effect ?

Comment: Have your **measurements** indicated there is a performance problem? If not, I would not bother.

Answer (score 0):

`setpriority` in a non-root process can only go up (decrease priority), never down.

What you can do is decrease process priority in the child process, before it execs the shell command.

```
//errror checks ommited
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid=fork();
    assert(pid>=0);
    if (!pid){
        execlp("nice", "nice", (char*)0);
        _exit(1);
    }
    wait(0);
    pid=fork();
    if (!pid){
        setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, 10);
        execlp("nice", "nice", (char*)0);
        _exit(1);
    }

}
/* should print:
    0
    10
*/
```

The performance overhead of a system call as simple as `setpriority` should be negligible compared to the cost of `fork` and `exec*`.